# How to convert string to logical expression in Python

Tags: python, string, expression, logical-operators

I need to convert a logical expression to not use parenthesis.
Basically I need the disjunctive normal form.

String input: `"(a | b) & c"`

Output: `a & c | b & c`

Comment: You should mark your answer accepted.

Comment: @BillBell I can't, red text says I can accept my question in 2 days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [pyeda](http://pyeda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/boolalg/expr.html) to parse your expression and even convert it.

```
print(expr.expr("(a | b) & c").to_dnf())
```

Output

```
Or(And(a, c), And(b, c))
```

Comment: Why are you answering yourself ?

Comment: @MatiasCicero he can, that's not an issue I think

Comment: Weird, but kosher: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @MatiasCicero the site offered me this instantly, "answer your question, share your knowledge".

Comment: @MiklósKosárkár I didn't know it was allowed, and I'm sure it's for a reason, but I'm guessing this applies to questions that hasn't been asnwered yet. This question, however, is a duplicate of [Disjunctive normal form in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27312328/disjunctive-normal-form-in-python)